# How to validate a entry in tkinter using python for inputs like 5.0e-7

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I want to know how the inputs to an entry widget in tkinter is validated so as to accommodate only digits, '-' symbols and letter 'e'. This widget is going to accept like 5.0e-7.Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches come to mind:

**Regex**

Check if the user's input matches the pattern of *[digits].[digits]e-[digits]* with regex:

```py
import re

user_input = '5.0e-7'

if re.match(r'\d+.\d+e-\d+', user_input):
    print('valid')
else:
    print('not valid')
```

**Float**

It looks like your widget is expecting exponential-format numbers, in which case python can convert them to a float without the need for regex. This would permit both negative (e.g. `5.0e-7`) and positive (e.g. `5.0e7`), which may or may not be what you're after:

```py
user_input = '5.0e-7'

try:
    float(user_input)
    print('valid')
except:
    print('not valid')
```

Comment: class ValidatedConv(ttk.Entry):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.configure(
        validate='all',
        validatecommand=(self.register(self.validate), '%P'),
        )
  def validate(self, input, **kwargs):
    user_input = '5.0e-7'
    if re.match(r'\d+.\d+e-\d+', user_input):
      return True
    else:
      return False

Comment: Do you mean like this?

Comment: If you add the relevant parts of your code to your original question in a nice format I can try and tailor my answer to what you've already got.